# Pontuar no output em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando resolver um problema, onde o usuário inseri `apenas` os números do cpf em um `input` e, ao lado, ele vai sendo exibido no formato correto do `CPF` (xxx.xxx.xxx-xx).

Porém, alguém sabe porque a pontuação aparece, mas depois que continuo digitando a pontuação some?

```
var inCPF = document.getElementById("inCPF");
var outCPF = document.getElementById("outCPF");

function formatar() {
    var cpf = inCPF.value;

    if (cpf.length == 3 || cpf.length == 7) {
        cpf += ".";
    } else if (cpf.length == 11) {
        cpf += "-";
    }

    outCPF.textContent = cpf;
}


inCPF.addEventListener("keyup", formatar);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está acontecendo esse problema pois no seu código é adicionado o `.` somente quando o tamanho é 3 ou 7: `if (cpf.length == 3 || cpf.length == 7)`. E o `-` somente quando o tamanho é 11: `else if (cpf.length == 11)`. Em outros casos não irá adicionar nada, ou seja, no final não adicionará os elementos.

O que recomendo fazer é pegar o `inCPF`, retirar os valores símbolos indesejáveis e colocar os caracteres, `.` e `-`, entre eles.

Ficaria desse jeito:

```js
var inCPF = document.getElementById("inCPF");
var outCPF = document.getElementById("outCPF");

function formatar() {
    var cpf = inCPF.value;
    //retira os caracteres indesejados e adiciona os novos
    cpf = cpf.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})?(\d{3})?(\d{2})?/, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
    //Aqui limita os caracteres exibidos no outCPF
    if(cpf.length <= 14){
        outCPF.textContent = cpf;
    }
}


inCPF.addEventListener("keyup", formatar);
```

```html
<input id="inCPF" maxlength="14">
<p id="outCPF"></p>
```

### EDIT

Fiz as alterações que me foram sugeridas nos comentários. Inclusive limitei o código para no máximo 14 caracteres.

Comment: É possível fazer isso sem usar RegExp?

Comment: Não conheço nenhuma outra forma de formatar o número enquanto digita sem ser com RegExp ou com jQuery. Mas caso queira fazer a formatação após digitar o número completo, existe diversas outras maneiras.

Comment: Detalhes: `[\d]` é o mesmo que `\d` (geralmente quando só tem um elemento entre colchetes, dá na mesma, mas aí não tem vantagem usar os colchetes então use sem: `\d{3}`, etc), e em vez de `[^0-9]` pode usar `\D`

Comment: tá aceitando algo desse tipo 123.456.789-01234

Comment: Editei segundo as sugestões de vocês.